# Setting up a dummy payment gateway for testing in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am new to the rails world and am in the process of setting up a small rails app for a client. One of the requirements is that I want to set a payment system for test purpose .

Answer (score 2):

For something quick, I would use Stripe. It has minimal backend setup, a gem, and (if you are into TDD) is easy to create tests with using given test card data.

```
gem install stripe
```